# Will electricity flow in a perfectly conductive medium?

Tags: resistors, physics, conductors

I was just wondering that since resistance is required for a potential difference to build up, what happens when we have a perfectly conducting wire, 0 resistance? Will current still flow through the medium? Or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: You might want to read up about superconductors.

Comment: You said it yourself: resistance is required to have a potential difference. Current doesn't need it.

Comment: You can simply conclude that there will be no voltage across the wire. The amount of current that will flow through it will simply depend on the rest of the circuit. If you put a perfect voltage source across it, of course, then you'll have a problem.

Comment: and if you want to measure that current do it indirectly through the magnetic field around the (super)conductor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, basically you're thinking about this wrong.

Ohm's law basically says: "for a resistor in isolation, you can relate Voltage, Current and Resistance." in other words if you know any two of those quantities you can determine the third one.

There is nothing more to it.  In this case, you know the *ideal* resistance = 0 and you have some amount of Current = I.  In the case of an ideal conductor you have Zero voltage drop across it, this comes from:

\$ V = I * R \$

\$V = I * 0\$

\$ V= 0 \$

What is telling is your statement "... that since resistance is required for a potential difference to build up ... "

That is the core of your misunderstanding and the core of where people go wrong.

A resistor in isolation is pretty useless, it isn't even a circuit. So a resistor cannot just decide to produce a voltage to if it is flowing a certain amount of current. So there is no voltage in the resistor to "build up" that voltage is imposed by the other other components in the circuit *only*.

An ideal Voltage Source will provide a fixed voltage and will flow as much current as possible to maintain that voltage.

An ideal current source will flow a fixed current and will provide as much Voltage as possible to ensure that current flows.

Your statement implies that the resistor generates the voltage.  In reality if you drive a resistor with a current source, the current source itself will generate the voltage necessary to maintain the current and since it is a resistor, you can't have a certain amount of current without also providing the voltage.

Of course I'm talking to ideal components here, but this is still useful.

So the answer is, in a superconductor you will get *zero* voltage drop along the length of the conductor.

Answer (score 2):

In a superconductor, there is no resistance and you can actually send current through it. The trick is here is that you can't use Ohm's law. Ohm's law apply at room temperature, quasi static and conservative system.

In a superconductor, the ohm's law doesn't hold and doesn't make any sense, infinite current doesn't make sense. A superconductor doesn't mean that you have a transfer of infinite current, it means that you can transfer energy on this type of line with out the loss of the line.

There is a maximum of current, you can push into these lines, the critical current. This limit is create by the current itself, because these high currents create strong magnetic field with the Meissner Effect at a certain value of current, the superconductivity collapse. The magnetic field can kill the superconductivity because the superconductivity depends on the spins of the electron and those spins interact with magnetic field.

Comment: Any edits on the last part concerning the physical explanation are welcome.

Comment: could you explain what you mean by " ... law apply to temperature piece, ..."

Comment: @placeholder at very low temperature, the conductor can switch to a superconductor state and at high temperature, the conductor most likely could melt and stop existing. I used the term room temperature to describe the range of temperature of the normal range of temperature used in electronics. The word "piece" was an error, I was thinking in French while writing the answer. Room temperature = temperature pièce in French. I will edit that error, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Ohm's Law: \$V=IR\$.

If \$R=0\$ then \$V=0\$, regardless of the value of \$I\$.

Beware of the Ohm's Law form: \$I=\frac{V}{R}\$, which can be indeterminate when \$R=0\$, i.e. \$I=\frac{0}{0}=?\$

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you connect a 1.5V battery across a perfectly conducting wire(0 ohm resistance). Then, yes, current would flow across the wire. But since the resistance of the wire is 0, there would be no potential difference/voltage drop across the wire.

It is true that potential difference is required to drive current. In any circuit, the potential difference is maintained by the power source/battery. For example, let's say a 10v battery is supplying power to a circuit. The battery maintains a potential difference of 10v across the terminals of the circuit. This 10v is divided across various components of the circuit depending on how much work is being done to push current across that component. If we were to consider a simple voltage divider as shown below,

[image: Simple voltage divider]

The battery maintains voltage "V" across R1 and R2. This voltage "V" gets divided into "V1" across "R1" and "V2" across "R2".(V=V1+V2) If R1>R2 then V1>V2 or vice versa. As resistance increases, more work needs to be done to push current through the component hence more voltage appears across that component. So, if the wire is perfectly conducting then NO WORK NEEDS TO BE DONE TO PUSH CURRENT THROUGH THE WIRE. Hence, maximum current would flow. If you were to connect this perfectly conducting wire directly across a battery, you would be short circuiting that battery because ideally infinite current would flow through the wire.

Long story short, resistance doesn't generate voltage/potential difference. Power source/battery does. A part of the potential difference generated by the battery appears across a component whenever work needs to be done(when there is resistance). If there is no resistance/no work needs to be done, current would still flow as long as battery is connected.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, electricity flows in a perfectly conductive medium and even in high or very high conductive mediums regardless the equations used to understand it.

Think about schematics or basic laboratory tests for simple circuits with resistors and batteries, we assume that wires have **zero-resistance** because they have a very low resistance value in comparison of the other elements, we consider those wires are simple points where electricity simply flows instantaneously, but it is not actually true. Ohm's law applies only in certain cases.

We use diferent mathematical and physical models for diferent conditions and materials. Just remember this examples where \$V \ne R \cdot I\$:

- Inductors: \$ V(t) = L\frac{{d\,I\left( t \right)}}{{dt}} \$
- Capacitors: \$ V(t) = \frac{1}{C}\int_{{t_0}}^t I (\tau ){\rm{d}}\tau  + V({t_0}) \$
- Diode (Shockley's ideal equation): \$ I = {I_{\rm{S}}}\left( {{e^{\frac{V}{{n{V_{\rm{T}}}}}}} - 1} \right) \$

Comment: "where electricity simply flows instantaneously" I would modify that... That is false and inaccurate.

Comment: @MathieuL: No, it's a true statement. When we think about circuits in the abstract, we do normally disregard any speed-of-propagation effects.

Comment: @DaveTweed I just comment that about because of the beginning of the  "all the wires in laboratory" I don't know who downvote the answer...

Comment: Following your suggestion @DaveTweed I tried to change that part of "all the wires..." to clarify better the idea, I fixed up a few typos and with grammar suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing feeders with loads.  The conducting medium feeds power to the load to do something useful.

After all if you apply any voltage to \$0\Omega\$, you will get \$\infty A\$. \$\infty\$ anything is always bad.

When you initially study Ohm's Law, you ignore losses.  Everything the source provides is delivered to the load.

$$I = \frac {V_S} {R}$$

But with a non-superconductor, the conducting medium has resistance (\$R_F\$)(the source has internal resistance, ect), so as current flows through the wires, there will be a voltage drop (losses) to the feeder, so that the voltage at the load will be less than the source. \$V_L < V_S\$.  Feeder and load form a series circuit and series rules apply.

The higher the load current, the greater the loss to the feeder.  If the wire is not sized correctly, the voltage lost to the feeder may be large enough so that the load may not work correctly (a motor may start but fail to operate under load or fail to start).  We use this relationship to design feeders to limit the voltage loss to the feeder to a specific maximum at rated current.

The classic examples are: when washing machines start up and lights (which shouldn't be on the same circuit) dim or loads at a large distance from the panel.

With a superconductor, no voltage is lost to the feeder and \$ V_L = V_S\$.  So theoretical Ohm's Law applies.  No losses.  100% efficiency (ignoring all other losses).

So superconductors would improve efficiency.  Make something that is impossible, possible, by limiting losses.

Comment: Division by 0 is not necessarily infinity. It is undefined. What the equations say are that there will be no voltage dropped regardless of what current flows through it. The voltage dropped will be \$V=IR=I\times0=0\$ which holds true for any current, it could be 1mA, 1A, 1GA.

Answer (score -3):

It needs a potential difference to have. But not longer than an instant moment for a superconductor. Wire may not have resistance. But will always have inductance. Electron can't move without inertia like light. You start the movement with that potential and keep its inertia without applying potential in lossless medium.